# I need help to create a skybox

Tags: javascript, three.js, background, scene, skybox

I have this website [project](https://replit.com/@OwenStritz/3js?v=1) that works but I want to add a skybox, and that doesn't work for me. Here's a code snippet of what's not working:

```
scene.background = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
  .setPath( '../img/' )
    .load( [
        'windows.png',
    'windows.png',
    'windows.png',
    'windows.png',
    'windows.png',
    'windows.png'
    ] );
```

Does anyone know how I get this to work? The code is copied from [threejs.org](https://threejs.org), I just changed the file paths which I think are correct so it should work but it doesn't. There are no error messages in the console.

Comment: “It's not working” [is not a question we can answer](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What does it do? What do you think it should do?

Comment: its suppost to add a skybox with six of the same images that are in a img folder called windows.png. the images are just the windows 11 logo because thats for some reason all i had in my files. right now its just an empty skybox thats black